# How can I increase limits of OSRM table function?

Tags: openstreetmap, open-source-routing-machine

I want to generate a distance matrix for more than 50 points with my own OSRM server. Because I want to minimize the number of calls, I decided to increase the size of the query from 50 to 100 or even more.

This is the answer of OSRM with 100 loc

```
{
  status_message: "Number of bearings does not match number of coordinates."
}
```

Query:

```
http:/.../table?loc=40.29864,-3.64438&loc=40.3986148,-3.6975552&...
```

I imagine there are limits, but is it possible to increase this limit?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution was launching the osrm-routed increasing the parameter --max-table-size with the desired size.

```
osrm-routed --max-table-size=1000 map.osrm
```

Comment: How is the computation time and memory usage compared to table size?

Comment: why am I not finding this anywhere in the documentation or even on searching the repo!