# Using OSRM with big queries?

Tags: open-source-routing-machine

I am experimenting with `table` service, the first restriction I thought about is the URL query length, as it work by http get request.

I need to send 5000 location, considering location is 35 characters long as for example:

> 35.921870470047,31.949649689353226;

thus, I will be sending `175000` character in the url, which is not possible I think for all browsers.

I will pass the result of durations matrix into the [vehicle routing problem solver](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/tsp/vehicle_routing) of Google Optimization Tools with the duarion matrix of a 5000 input location.

Here is an example of my query for small number of locations:

http://router.project-osrm.org/table/v1/driving/35.921870470047,31.949649689353226;35.88357925415039,31.974007590177635;35.92055082321167,31.948830365146534

Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to **set up your own instance of OSRM** for a 5000x5000 input matrix. The hosted version at router.project-osrm.org only supports small matrices.
When working with your own instance, you can change the `max-table-size` parameter (see also [How can I increase limits of OSRM table function?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178669/how-can-i-increase-limits-of-osrm-table-function))

To reduce the the number of characters in the URL, you can **encode the points** using [Google's polyline algorithm](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm). (Don't worry, there are libraries for JavaScript and other common languages to do this).

Comment: Easiest option is to use docker for this: https://hub.docker.com/u/osrm/

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue. I fixed by forking OSRM and adding the support for Http POST, and sending all these parameters in the POST body instead of the Url. You can take a look at my [OSRM fork](https://github.com/sayanb1983/osrm-backend). But the caveat is that you have to host the OSRM server yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For URL issue you can use Lua language in Nginx configuration:

```
access_by_lua_block {
    if ngx.var.request_method == "POST" then
        ngx.req.read_body()
        local data = ngx.req.get_body_data()
        ngx.req.set_uri(ngx.var.uri .. data)
    end
}
proxy_connect_timeout        600;
proxy_send_timeout           600;
proxy_read_timeout           600;
send_timeout                 600;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
}
```

Add above code in `/etc/nginx/site-enabled/<osrm.conf>` and enable Lua in Nginx. then you can send your request in post body and Nginx append post body to end of URL. for example:

```
curl "https://<your_server_url>/table/v1/car/" -X POST --data-raw "51.674905,32.662381;51.643285,32.651122;51.674986,32.677698?annotations=duration"1"
```